# Displaying users with 2 related tables records

Tags: laravel, angular, laravel-5.3, eloquent

I have 3 Models :

User, Role and Branch.

They are related like this :

Pour User model :

```
class User extends Model
{
    // Define fields to be fillable
    protected $fillable = [
                            'firstname', 
                            'lastname',
                            'telephone',
                            'address',
                            'password',
                            'code',
                            'status',
                            'branches_id',
                            'roles_id'
                        ];

    /**
     * Get the role record associated with the user.
     */
    public function role()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Role');
    }

    /**
     * Get the branch record associated with the user.
     */
    public function branch()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Branch');
    }
}
```

For Role Model :

```
class Role extends Model
{
    // Define fields to be fillable
    protected $fillable = ['description'];

    /**
     * Get the user that owns the role.
     */
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User');
    }
}
```

For branch model :

```
class Branch extends Model
{
    // Define fields to be fillable
    protected $fillable = ['description', 'location'];

    /**
     * Get the user that owns the branch.
     */
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User');
    }
}
```

I know that if i was using Blade, to list user's roles, i could have done something like : $user->role()

But i am trying to use angular 2 for the frontend and laravel 5.3 for my backend.

My question is how to retrieve users along with roles and branches


Here is my index action in my UserController:

```
public function index()
{
    // Get all users, along with roles and branches
    $users = User::all();

    // Send the response
    return response()->json([
            'users' => $users
        ], 200);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading):

```
$users = User::with('role', 'branch')->get();
```

Also if user has one role and one branch, relationships should be `belongsTo()` instead of `belongsToMany()`:

```
return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
```

Comment: This may help others, i have created other models 'Transfer', 'status'. 'transfer' is linked to 'status' and 'user'. I wanted to display all transfers will all its relations and all users relations, I just did : $transfers = Transfer::with('status', 'user', 'user.branch', 'user.role')->get()

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `with()` method for this, e.g.

```
$users = User::with('role')->get();
```

See https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading for more information